# How to send log to Cloud Watch in C# application

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, nlog, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to be able to send application logs to `Cloud Watch Log`. and I got to know that there is a `Cloud Watch Agent` service that runs in the background and reads logs from log file and send only the delta (extra logs) to `Cloud Watch Log`. All this makes sense to me. Then I got to know about NLog a C# logging framework, and wrote below POC to send logs.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConfigureNLog();
    var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Info("Hello World");
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Sample informational message");
}
static void ConfigureNLog()
{
        var accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AWSAccessKey");
        var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AWSSecretKey");
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        var awsTarget = new AWSTarget()
        {
            LogGroup = "NLog.ProgrammaticConfigurationExample",
            Region = "us-east-1",
            Credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
        };
        config.AddTarget("aws", awsTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, awsTarget));

        LogManager.Configuration = config;
}
```

Now when I run above code, I am able to send log to Cloud Watch. But I am confused now, where is the significance of Cloud Watch Agent?

1. Since I am directly sending log data, does that mean I don't need Cloud Watch Agent in my scenario?
2. In case I want to use `Cloud Watch Agent` then I need to use `FILE` as a target for logs by `NLog` and then tell Cloud Watch Agent to send that log file to Cloud Watch Log??

Is my understanding correct? Please help me in understanding the flow.

Is below flow correct?

> NLog write log to File -> Cloud Agent read log from there -> Send log
>   to Cloud Watch

**Question:** How to use Cloud Watch Agent in above POC to send data via NLog?

Comment: Log monitoring agents are usually given directories to look in where it pulls logs from. If you're using an API to send logs to Cloud Watch, and not looking to reap any of the other monitoring benefits of the agent, then it's not necessary to install an agent.

Comment: So, if I need to capture app level logs then I don't need to use any Agent?

Comment: No, you can just interact with an API, should one be exposed. You can however use the agent to pull other log sources for better monitoring of your infrastructure.

Comment: @ColinM: Ok here is the things, suppose I explicitly want to use an Agent, then in that case, it will be mandatory for me to set `NLog` logging framework target to set to some file, so that I can direct my Agent to go look for that file and send data.

Comment: Yes.. what's the question?

Comment: @ColinM : To simply put my question, I want to send log to cloud watch using the cloud watch agent, and NOT the way I have sent in my POC above, how to achieve that? Please guide me.

Comment: What changes required in above code to allow cloud watch agent to be able to send logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Watch Agent runs on your server and can watch logs files that are produced.  These log files can be anything, IIS Logs, Time Logs, Event Log, Etc.  When the log file is updated, CWA will grab the updates and send to Cloud Watch.  This is the generic behavior of the CWA and is great for Event Logs and OS logging.

By modifying the AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.json CWA json file, you can configure it to watch log files for certain formats and send changes to CW outside the standard/example ones it does by default.  You can update the json to your NLog entry layout format and have it watch for that specific format in the file.  CW Does have a delay sending.

Now you have Nlog which writes log files.  You can have NLog send the log entries to a file and have the Cloud Watch Agent watch that file, pick up the change and send it or you can have NLog send the entries directly to CW. Since you are writing directly to CW through a NLog target, you don't need the Cloud Agent for your NLog files.  I suggest keeping CWA for other log files like IIS or event logs.

I guess it is a matter a preference on how you do it.  I think NLog Targets with layouts is easier than dealing with the CloudWatch json file to try and match the  log format. I only use CWA to send log files I have no control over and use a NLog Target to send my NLog entries.

I can post an example CWA json snippet for a 3rd party log file I monitor with CWA if you need an example.

Comment: `I suggest keeping CW for other log files like IIS or event logs.` Is there a typo in this statement? Do you mean CW or CWA in this line?

Comment: And Just to be completely sure since I am targeting CW Logs directly via NLog config, I do not need to use CWA in my scenario right?

Comment: @Unbreakable Thanks - Fixed Typo, CWA I would keep if you already have it installed. I am not sure on the AWS Alarms if CWA is needed at least for that, I have always had it installed.  I would let it be and let it do what it does for AWS.  Since you are going directly to CW,  CWA is not needed for your app.

Comment: Thank you so so much. I will ping you here if I have more questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

When an application just have to write to a file, then it lives a very simple life with few problems.

When an application suddenly have to handle network traffic (with timeouts, disconnects, retries, connectivity, latency, etc.) then it suddenly will have issues with things queuing up, taking memory, using sockets, causing garbage collections, stalls, etc. (And loosing all pending logevents on crash)

Depending on the lifetime of your application and the critically of your applications, then it can be useful to give it a simple life. And let a friend like `Cloud Watch Agent` worry about the network-stuff.

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-cloud-logging-with-Azure-function-or-AWS-lambda

Comment: My app will be highly complex, so, if I want to use an Agent to capture logs of my app, then it is MANDATORY for me to let NLog write log to a file and then let the Agent Read it from there? Am I making sense? What about the POC I have written above, I am not writing to any file or anything and still I am able to send logs.

Comment: What is the flow. `1. Nlog -> write to a file 2. Agent picks it up 3. Sends it to Clod Watch Log`

Comment: I want to know the flow of using Cloud Watch Logs.

Comment: Sounds like a different question, than whether to use Cloud Watch Agent or not. Maybe read the documentation: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/systems-manager/latest/userguide/monitoring-cloudwatch-agent.html

Comment: Can you please tell me the flow of getting data to Cloud Watch, that's all I need to know. What should be set as target for NLog when I want Cloud Agent to send Logs.? target for NLog should be file, or console, or AWS just like my POC above. All I want to know is How to use Cloud Watch Agent with NLOG to send logs?

Comment: `How to use Cloud Watch Agent in above POC to send data via NLog?`

Comment: StackOverflow is not a website where we'll pick the best way for you to feed logs into a monitoring tool, that's up to you. There are many ways for you to push or poll logs to a monitoring tool, you've come across the primary 2 ways, now understand your requirements and pick an option. How to use CloudWatch agent? Read the manual as previously mentioned.

Comment: @ColinM: I have asked alot of question on Stack Overflow (290 ques) but may be I am not able to describe my question properly. I only want to know what should be the target of my NLog which will allow the cloud agent to pick up the logs. Do I need to have target as File or Console or what? As per my current POC I am simply writing statement like `logger.Trace/Debug...` and I am able to send it to cloud watch.

Comment: Where shall my application should send logs, so that it can be picked up by Cloud Watch Agent and hence can be sent to Cloud Watch Log? I don't know if I can simplify my question more. :-|